# What is WPF/C# equivalent of Panda's DataFrame

Tags: c#, wpf, dataframe

So I worked with Panda's Dataframe and it is as you know very good in Data Analysis such as filtering. I am wondering what C# has to offer? I came across C# DataTable! is this C# take on DataFrame?

Comment: Not sure what panda data frame is..... but in C# there is just so many ways to work with data that this question is too broad for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

For data analysis Ml.Net introduced a similar Data Frame https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.analysis.dataframe?view=ml-dotnet-preview

But for routine business apps, there’s the DataTable as you have found.